# How to convert Varchar to Double in sql?

Tags: mysql, sql, numeric, varchar

I have problem with my query when I was trying to convert the varchar field to double (numeric). I have this sql statement:

```
SELECT fullName, CAST(totalBal as numeric(9,2) FROM client_info ORDER BY totalBal DESC
```

Actually I want to display the values of `totalBal` in descending order. But since that field is in varchar, the resultset is sometimes wrong. This is the resultset when I tried to query using this statement:

```
SELECT fullName, totalBal FROM client_info ORDER BY totalBal DESC
```

Resultset is:

[image]

The sorting of `totalBal` is not correct. So I decided to convert the varchar to numeric so that it might be sorted perfectly. Any idea?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

use `DECIMAL()` or `NUMERIC()` as they are fixed precision and scale numbers.

```
SELECT fullName, 
       CAST(totalBal as DECIMAL(9,2)) _totalBal
FROM client_info 
ORDER BY _totalBal DESC
```

Comment: Thank you for this idea... updated the code with this... 
`SELECT fullName, CAST( totalBal AS DECIMAL( 9, 2 ) ) AS totBal
FROM client_info
ORDER BY totBal DESC`

Answer (score 3):

This might be more desirable, that is use float instead

```
SELECT fullName, CAST(totalBal as float) totalBal FROM client_info ORDER BY totalBal DESC
```

Comment: "CAST as float" is not valid in MySQL. So this doesn't work at all.

Comment: The question is about SQL, not about MySQL and CAST as float is valid SQL.

Comment: The first tag in question is `mysql` so it was perhaps my bad I answered `MSSQL` version.